# python nested json ararys

Tags: python, json

im accessing an API, sample here (https://developer.pagerduty.com/documentation/rest/escalation_policies/on_call)

```
SUBDOMAIN='XXX'
API_ACCESS_KEY='XXX'

headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Token token={0}'.format(API_ACCESS_KEY),
    'Content-type': 'application/json',
}
url = 'https://{0}.pagerduty.com/api/v1/escalation_policies/on_call'.format(SUBDOMAIN)
r = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
objData = r.json()


for objPolicy in objData['escalation_policies']:
    print objPolicy['name']
    for objOnCall in objPolicy['on_call']:
        print objOnCall['level']
        print objOnCall['start']
        print objOnCall['end']
        for objUser in objOnCall['user']:
            print objUser['name']
```

im currently getting the error

```
    print objUser['name']
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

if my understand is right, [] is a list, {} is an object? so im trying to access a object as a list thats why its not working?

The ammount of nesting is quite hard to understand for a newbie. can someone explain and show me how to access each user on that on_call policy?

Thanks

Comment: The code was able to retrieve the object fine. The problem is that it looks like objUser is a string itself. I would add a debug line after the for statement `print objUser` and see what it prints.

Comment: You're trying to access a *string* as if it was a dictionary, not a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [API documentation](https://developer.pagerduty.com/documentation/rest/escalation_policies/on_call), there is an object (think "dictionary") under the `user`:

```
...
"user": {
    "id": "P9TX7YH",
    "name": "Cordell Simonis",
    "email": "email_1@acme.pagerduty.dev",
    "time_zone": "Pacific Time (US & Canada)",
    "color": "dark-goldenrod"
}
```

To reflect that, modify your code to:

```
user = objOnCall['user']  # user is a dictionary
print(user['name'])  # getting a value from a dictionary by a key
```